# I want Ubuntu to be a Miracast host, and the video coming in to be available as /dev/videoX

Tags: upnp, wifi-direct

Are there any projects that are capable of being a Miracast host, and that make the video available through video4linux (/dev/videoX)?

Answer (score 0):

It's been several months, but you might want to look into the [Miraclecast project](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast), or better still, contact the developer of that project directly to see if you can use `/dev/videoX`.